# Codeigniter 403 Forbidden Error when send the data through ajax

Tags: ajax, codeigniter-3

I've built a simple project using Codeigniter 3 and when I send an ajax request using `$.ajax` method in localhost it works perfectly but I get

> "403 Forbidden"

error when I do so on live server.
I set `$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;` and `$config['csrf_regenerate'] = FALSE;` in config.php.
This is the js code which sends data using ajax.

```
     $.ajax({
        url : '/login/authenticate',
        type : 'post',
        data : $(this).serialize(),
        success : function(response) {
            if (response.state == false) {
                var msg = response.msg;
                err_msg(msg);
            } else {
                if(response.type == "admin"){
                    window.location.href ='/admin';    
                } else {
                    window.location.href = '/user';
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Please tell me how to resolve this issue.
This is my login controller

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('login_view');
}

//check the email and password and log the user in if the user info is correct
public function authenticate()
{   
    $this->load->model("userModel","user", true);
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    //Form validation - codeigniter provides you with powerful form validation functionality
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $res = array('state' => false, 'msg' => validation_errors());
    } else {
        $type = $this->user->login($email, $password);
        if ($type == "user" ) {
            $res   = array('state' => true, 'type' => $type, 'msg' => 'You are logged in!');
            $toast = array('state' => true, 'msg' => 'You are logged in!');
            $this->session->set_flashdata('toast', $toast);

        }else if($type == "admin"){
            $res   = array('state' => true, 'type' => $type, 'msg' => 'You are logged in!');
            $toast = array('state' => true, 'msg' => 'You are logged in!');
            $this->session->set_flashdata('toast', $toast);
        }else if ($type == -3) {
            $msg = "You can't be logged in because you are not active at the moment.";
            $res = array('state' => false, 'msg' => $msg);
        }else if ($type == -1) {
            $msg = "Wrong Password!";
            $res = array('state' => false, 'msg' => $msg);
        }else {
            $msg = "You were not registered!";
            $res = array('state' => false, 'msg' => $msg);
        }
    }
    return $this->output
                ->set_content_type('application/json')
                ->set_output(json_encode($res));        
}
}
```

Comment: hi, it still doesn't work

Comment: Same issue when commenting out the line $this->session->set_flashdata  works well

Answer (score 0):

Hi I didn't get any error while using the above code..see below images

[image]

use form name or form ID to serialize data instead of $(this).serialize()

Answer (score 0):

i think you forgot to set `.htaccess` configuration.

so please create a new file in the root of project name it **.htaccess** and paste code below in it

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /pishtazan/ # this is for the subfolder in my localhost if you work online remove name of folder
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /pishtazan/index.php [PT,L] #also here you can rename/delete folder name 
</IfModule>
```

if you don't want or it conflict your whole project simply you can edit your javascript ajax url to `'index.php/login/authenticate'` and try it